# Is it possible to have a constructor with 1 input parameter of undeclared type?

Tags: c++, types, constructor

Here is what I an trying to do:

1. Class with two objects (`string myStr` and `int myInt`)
2. Constructor takes in **1 parameter** (data type not fixed).
3. `If` parameter is string: `myStr = parameter; myInt = parameter.length();`
4. `If` parameter is int: `myInt = parameter; myStr = "0000...0"`
   (string of length "parameter", set by for loop)
5. `Else` : `cout << "Error";`

Is it possible to do what I am describing in line 2?

I've managed to do some workarounds using only strings and converting data types (able to do this when imposing an artificial lower bound for length of `myStr`) however this is causing me other issues further down the line.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about function overloading. You can just provide two constructors, one that takes `int` and one that takes `std::string` and implement them however you want.

Comment: You know you can define multiple constructors right?

Comment: Regarding `5.`: You shouldn't do any runtime output for this. If you try to construct your class instance with an unsupported constructor argument type, i.e. if you didn't write a constructor for that type, the compiler will simply fail the compilation with an error message, which is much better than seeing the error only at runtime.

Comment: Of course a template constructor can be used which seems to be able to fulfill those requirements, but the resulting code is just unnecessarily complex compared to defining 3 overloads for options 3. to 5. in addition to allowing you to cause a compile time error instead of a runtime error for 5....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a constructor with 1 input parameter of undeclared type?

Technically, you can have variadic parameters which allows unspecified number of arguments of unspecified types. But I recommend against using it.

The types of all other parameters must be declared.

> - If parameter is string: myStr = parameter; myInt = parameter.length();
> - If parameter is int: myInt = parameter; myStr = "0000...0" (string of length "parameter", set by for loop)

You can easily achieve this using two constructors instead of one. One that accepts a string and another that accepts an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not using a single parameter, but that you need later to find out the type of data of the parameter.

A commonly used trick it's to use either a generic Pointer, or a generic object class reference or Pointer.

```
MyClass::MyClass ( void* P );
MyClass::MyClass ( SomeBaseClass& P);
```

Since You are working for more simple data, You may want to try an O.O. approach like nesting the values in objects, and later, checking the type of the data:

```
class BaseClass
{
  // ...
} ;

class IntegerClass: BaseClass
{
  int Value;
} ;

class StringClass: BaseClass
{
  String Value;
} ;
```

And your class can receive a "BaseClass" object reference:

```
class MyClass
{
  private int MyInt;
  private String MyString;
  
  MyClass ( BaseClass& P ) 
  {
     if ( P is IntegerClass )
     {
       // 
     }
     else if ( P is StringClass )
     {
       //
     }
  }
} ;

int main (...)
{
  IntegerClass *i = new IntegerClass(5);
  StringClass *s = new StringClass ("Hello");
  
  MyClass *O1 = new MyClass(i);
  MyClass *O2 = new MyClass(s);
  
  // Display values of O1 and O2 here
  
  free O2;
  free O1;
   
  free s;
  free i;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Just my two bitcoins ...

Comment: @user17732522 There's no such thing as `void&` used in My code example...